# move uploaded file issue

Tags: php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    session_start();
    $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;
    $ext=$_GET['ext'];
    $src = $_GET['p'];

    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    unlink($src);
    imagejpeg($dst_r,$src,$jpeg_quality);
    rename($src,"img/temp_images/".$_SESSION['userid'].".".$ext);

    $result=move_uploaded_file(
                        "/img/temp_images/".$_SESSION['userid'].".$ext",

                        "/img/".$_SESSION['userid'].".$ext");
    if($result)
    echo "Success";
    else
    echo "<br>Fail";


?>
```

1. Safe mode is off
2. No error is displayed despite of putting the following code

   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
3. The system is running on localhost
4. Everything is working except move_uploaded_file() function
5. The code is called from an iframe.
6. Also I have tried directory(**FILE**) and many alternatives

Please suggest a solution or a reason to the problem. Do I need to catch the error/warning somewhere using the firs 3 lines? I'm running this on a XAMPP setup ver 2.5.8. I assume since I'm able to create files, I have the permissions to move the file to a folder. And I guess on a localhost there is no hassle for permissions?

Comment: I doubt the path `/img/...` is correct. You have a folder `img` **at the root of your hard disk**?!

Comment: `"/img/temp_images/".$_SESSION['userid'].".$ext",` - what is this? Why are you using it? Why do you think your file is there? You should have there something like: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], "/img/".$_SESSION['userid'].".$ext"(;`

Comment: //unlink-Delete the file.
problem is that you put unlink before move_uploaded_file,which results unlink remove your file before upload.you should put unlink after move_uploaded_file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new image using GD library. Instead of `move_uploaded_file()` try use `copy` which to move files from one location to another location

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Code Example,

```
if (copy($old_file, $new_file)) {
    unlink($old_file);
}
```

Comment: Hey the copy function worked just as I wanted :-) Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @user1435686 Welcome! If my answer is helpful, then set this as correct answer and vote me up.